# Laravel: property of non-object

Tags: laravel, url

Trying to fix the issue with "Trying to get property of non-object"  and I almost done by changing all the $item->product_id to $item['product_id'] and it worked except one object. I have one image url needs to be fixed as well which I am confused how to do it

Here is the code:

```
<img src="{{ asset($item->product->productImages->first()->path) }}" alt="img">
```

Comment: `$item->product` or `$item->product->productImages->first()` is returning `null`, and you can't access properties of `null`. Debug your code; never assume `$object->property` is valid code.

Comment: Its not returning me Null. There is a proper image path that I can see when I dd()

Comment: Is that the line of code that is causing the error? Is that in a loop of any kind? Is `$item` always the same variable, or is it based off a database query? You're gonna have to provide more details if you say that line works without issue.

Comment: I am just asking how to change the ->first() and ->path like I did for remaining part asset($item->product->productImages to asset($item['product']['productImages']

Comment: And yes this line of code is causing problem, because when I removed it then it works fine. And yes its in a loop. I need to render proper image path

Comment: Why would you use array syntax on this? What is `$item`? Is it a `Model`? I mean, you could do `$item['product']['productImages'][0]['path]`, but if **any** of those are null, you're gonna get an error...

Comment: It already solved by Davit

Comment: Well yeah, because `$item->product->productImages->first()` was returning `null`, like I said in the comments above... But whatever; glad you got it solved. Just be aware that when you use the same code in a loop, just because the first iteration works **does not mean that all iterations will**. `dd()` will only test the first iteration of the loop, so it was the 2nd, 3rd, etc that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
@if(!empty($item->product->productImages->first()))
    <img src="{{ asset($item->product->productImages->first()->path) }}" alt="img">
@endif
```